Third party library mocked with Jest still tries to access internals
I have a function as such:
export type SendMessageParams = {
  chatSession?: ChatSession,
  // ... other params ...
};

const sendMessage = async ({
  chatSession,
  // ... other params ...
}: SendMessageParams): Promise<void> => {
  // await chatSession?.sendMessage()
  // somewhere in implementation
};

export default sendMessage;

ChatSession is from @google/generative-ai.
I'd like to mock it in my test file as such:
let defaultParams: SendMessageParams;

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.mock('@google/generative-ai', () => ({
    ChatSession: {
      sendMessage: async (content: string) => content,
    },
  }));
  defaultParams = {
    chatSession: new ChatSession('', ''),
    // ... other params ...
  };
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

it('should send message', async () => {
  // await sendMessage();
});

When I run npm run test, I get the error saying:
 FAIL  tests/logic/actions/sendMessage.test.ts
  ● should send message

    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

      43 |   const sendMessageInner = async (messages: Message[]) => {
      44 |     setMessageListState(messages);
    > 45 |     const result = await chatSession?.sendMessage(content);
         |                    ^
      46 |     const responseText = result?.response.text();
      47 |     if (responseText) {
      48 |       const responseMessage: Message = {

      at makeRequest (node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:246:9)
      at generateContent (node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:655:28)
      at node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:890:25
      at ChatSession.sendMessage (node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:909:9)
      at sendMessageInner (src/logic/actions/sendMessage.ts:45:20)
      at src/logic/actions/sendMessage.ts:72:7
      at sendMessage (src/logic/actions/sendMessage.ts:59:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/logic/actions/sendMessage.test.ts:44:3)


...which hints that chatSession.sendMessage method still uses the real implementation instead of mock.
I'd like to know why this happens and what the solution would be.
Thanks in advance.

Environment

Node 20.11.0 (lts/iron)
Jest 29.7.0
@google/generative-ai 0.5.0 (if relevant)


This approach never worked for me, I usually use manual mock folder -> https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules which works fine, but you have to define all methods you use and mock them, but lets chatGPT do it :)

Since the sendMessage function accepts a chatSession as its parameter. You can create a mock chatSession and pass it to sendMessage. You don't need to use jest.mock().
e.g.
index.ts:
import { ChatSession } from "@google/generative-ai";

export type SendMessageParams = {
  chatSession?: ChatSession;
};

const sendMessage = async ({ chatSession }: SendMessageParams): Promise<void> => {
  await chatSession?.sendMessage('hello');
};

export default sendMessage;

index.test.ts:
import { ChatSession } from '@google/generative-ai';
import sendMessage from '.';

it('should send message', async () => {
  const chatSession = {
    sendMessage: jest.fn().mockImplementation((content) => content),
  } as unknown as ChatSession;

  await sendMessage({ chatSession });
  expect(chatSession.sendMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');
});

